# Cross-Fade transitions using React-Navigation bottom Tab

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I was working with react navigation, and I noticed there is ways to animate a Screen Content using Stack Navigator.
Reading more about motion system provided by Material UI, I haven't found a way that I could animate Bottom Tab Navigator (or Material Bottom Tab), to follow the guidelines described here: [Material UI Motion System](https://material.io/design/motion/the-motion-system.html#fade-through).
I've seen ways to implement Fading In, but now Fade Through.

Answer (score 1):

I figured an answer, pretty much the only way I found was doing some event based approach. Listening to tabPress, and Focus event.

I implemented the solution on this small project: [Cross Fade Project](https://github.com/getuliovdmnaweb/fade-through-bottom-tab/blob/main/App.js)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).